# Android NDK: Inter-process transfers of AHardwareBuffer via Binder

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-binder

I am writing a C++ library to allow two Android applications to communicate and exchange data. The server-side appication is pure C++ too, with a small amount of Java to create a service/activity. Some of the shared data is best managed by `AHardwareBuffer` objects, as according to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/a-hardware-buffer) they provide zero-copy/shared memory view of the underlying data.

Because of this, I was initially planning to use abstract Unix Domain Sockets, and then NDK's [AHardwareBuffer_sendHandleToUnixSocket](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/a-hardware-buffer#ahardwarebuffer_sendhandletounixsocket) and [AHardwareBuffer_recvHandleFromUnixSocket](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/a-hardware-buffer#ahardwarebuffer_recvhandlefromunixsocket) for the transfer. However I discovered recent [Android security changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#framework-security-changes) now deny Unix Domain Sockets for IPC. These deny my client application from connecting to the server's socket.

Then I started looking into Binder and AIDL as this seems to be the recommended way of doing IPC. However I cannot see how Binder could work with AHardwareBuffer.

I've thought about the following but am not sure which one to pursue further:

1. Create a pair of connected sockets on the server side, send one to the client over Binder (I've spotted [AParcel_writeParcelFileDescriptor](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/ndk-binder#aparcel_writeparcelfiledescriptor) and its read counterpart in NdkBinder). However I am not sure whether SELinux will allow reads and writes from/to the socket in the untrusted app.
2. Using JNI to convert from AHardwareBuffer to a Java HardwareBuffer, and then using [writeToParcel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/HardwareBuffer#writeToParcel(android.os.Parcel,%20int)). NdkBinder then has [AParcel_fromJavaParcel](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/ndk-binder#aparcel_fromjavaparcel). However I don't see how that will work on the other side - nothing along the lines of `AParcel_toJavaParcel()` in the NDK or how to turn a Java Parcel back into a Java NativeBuffer. For the latter I was looking at [readParcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel#readParcelable(java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)), but in general this method of going between Java and C++ seems very messy.
3. Looking at the NdkBinder API, there's a bunch of `AParcel_read*` and `AParcel_write*` functions, but the only ones that are remotely relevant are the `ParcelableArray` ones. But I cannot find online examples on how they can be used. Is a "parcelable" here a `jobject` which corresponds to a type which implements `android.os.Parcelable`? If the Java APIs for [Parcel.readParceableArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel#readParcelableArray(java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) are the NDK's direct counterparts then this would suggest so. In this case I reckon this may be my best option. Also - if this method is viable, does it still preserve the zero-copy nature of the AHardwareBuffer transfer?